# Kotlin - How to concatenate XML strings in dialog box

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a multiple choice quiz app. If the user answers incorrectly, a dialog box shows a string (citation for a journal/book) from XML.

Depending on the question, I may need hardcoded text and one or more strings to show in the dialog box. Given the number of strings and potential arrangements, combining strings needed for each question into new string resources would be cumbersome.

Is there a way that I can concatenate hardcoded text with multiple string resources to show in the same dialogBox?

For example:

```
"This is the reason why your answer was incorrect"
String citation 1   
String citation 2
```

XML

```
<resources>
    <string name="Johnson_1982"> Author, Article title (1982). <i>Article Source.</i></string>
    <string name="Kelly_2006"> Author, Article title (2006). <i>Article Source.</i></string>
<resources>
```

dialogBox

```
val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        dialogBuilder.setMessage(questions2.dialogBox)
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setNegativeButton("Close", DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                                    dialog, id -> dialog.cancel()
                            })
                        val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
                        alert.show()
```

Data class

```
data class Questions2(val id: Int, val question: String, val option1: String, val option2: String, val option3: String, val option4: String, val correctAnswer: Int, val dialogBox: Int)
```

For example, for q1, I only need 1 string value, q2, 2 string values, and q3, hard coded string plus 2 string values. The app crashes given `R.string.Johnson_1982 + R.string.Kelly_2006`

```
object ConstantsAnalysis {
    const val TOTAL_CORRECT: String = "total_correct"
    const val TOTAL_OPP: String = "total_opp"
    fun getQuestions2(): ArrayList<Questions2> {
        val questionList = ArrayList<Questions2>()
        val options = ArrayList<TextView>()
        val q1 = Questions2(1, "Question A:","A","B","C","D", 3, R.string.Johnson_1982)
        val q2 = Questions2(2, "Question B:","A","B","C","D", 2, R.string.Johnson_1982 + R.string.Kelly_2006)
        val q3 = Questions2(3, "Question C:","A","B","C","D", 1, "Reason why answer is incorrect" + R.string.Johnson_1982 + R.string.Kelly_2006) 
        questionList.addAll(listOf(q1, q2, q3))
        questionList.shuffle()
        return questionList
    }
}
```

If I create a second `dialogBox` to concatenate with the first, the app crashes (i.e. `dialogBuilder.setMessage(questions2.dialogBox + questions2.dialogBox2!!)`

Same goes for `dialogBuilder.setMessage("Reason why answer was incorrect" + questions2.dialogBox)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I created separate vars for the text and Strings. I also reformatted the code to handle when either of the dialogBoxes is null.

New data class

```
data class Questions2(id: Int, val image: Int?, val question: String, val option1: String, val option2: String, val option3: String, val option4: String, val correctAnswer: Int, val answerString: String, val dialogBox: Int?, val dialogBox2: Int?)
```

New dialogBox

```
            if (questions2!!.correctAnswer != mSelectedOptionPosition) {
                answerView(mSelectedOptionPosition, R.drawable.incorrect_option_border_bg)
                val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                when {
                    questions2.dialogBox!=null && questions2.dialogBox2!=null -> {
                        dialogBuilder.setMessage(questions2.answerString + "\n\n" + getString(questions2.dialogBox) + "\n\n" + getString(questions2.dialogBox2))
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setNegativeButton(
                                "Close"
                            ) { dialog, id ->
                                dialog.cancel()
                            }
                        val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
                        alert.show()
                    }
                    questions2.dialogBox!=null && questions2.dialogBox2 == null -> {
                        dialogBuilder.setMessage(questions2.answerString + "\n\n" + getString(questions2.dialogBox))
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setNegativeButton(
                                "Close"
                            ) { dialog, id ->
                                dialog.cancel()
                            }
                        val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
                        alert.show()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because R.string.Johnson_1982 is the reference to the string resource not the string itself. what you need is this:

```
getString(R.string.Johnson_1982)
```

the above class gives you the text value of your string
so change your code this way:

change your object to a class and use it this way:

```
class ConstantsAnalysis (context: Context) {
    ...
    val q1 = Questions2(1, "Question A:","A","B","C","D", 3, context.getString(R.string.Johnson_1982))
}
```

Comment: This yields the following error: `Unresolved reference: getString`